# Query SQLVERSION genera error con distintas bases de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables, mssql

tengo este extraño comportamiento usando MSSQL

Resulta que está consulta me da diferentes valores en una base de datos que corre en la misma instancia de servidor de SQL SERVER.

> Select case when SERVERProperty('ProductVersion') < '11.0.2%' then 0
> else 1 End as sqlnroversion

La consulta devuelve 0 cuando el valor de versión del motor de base de datos es inferior a 11.0.2 y 1 cuando es superior a esa versión.

El problema es que con una base de datos restaurada en una instancia 2014 me arroja como versión 12.0.2 pero me devuelve 0 cuando debería ser 1, y es la única base de datos que devuelve 0 las demás devuelven 1 correctamente.

Alguno me podía orientar que es lo que sucede.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que comparara valores numéricos, la expresión que utilizas (`SERVERProperty('ProductVersion') < '11.0.2%'`) no sirve para comparar un valor numérico.

Puedes probar convirtiendo el "ProductoVersion" en un entero:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN
  CASE 
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '8%' THEN 2000
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '9%' THEN 2005
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '10.0%' THEN 2008
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '10.5%' THEN 2009
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '11%' THEN 2012
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '12%' THEN 2014
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '13%' THEN 2016    
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '14%' THEN 2017
     WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(128), SERVERPROPERTY ('ProductVersion')) like '15%' THEN 2019
     ELSE 2050
  END < 11 then 0 else 1 End as sqlnroversion
```

Siguiendo con [el versionado de SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1140/how-to-tell-what-sql-server-version-you-are-running/), dónde 11 se corresponde con la versión 2012, 12 con la 2014, etc.

Answer (score 0):

resulta que el error si estaba en la dB, al realizar un DBCC CHECKDB, la base de datos comenzó a responder y devolver los querys normalmente, sin tener que cambiar nada en la consulta base. por lo que la consulta inicial que les envíe sigue funcionando correctamente.

Select case when SERVERProperty('ProductVersion') < '11.0.2%' then 0 else 1 End as sqlnroversion